# In Sublime Text, how do I find and replace all non-coded web addresses with formatted and linked URLs?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, find-replace

how do I find and replace all non-coded web addresses with formatted and linked URLs?

The dummy text in the example below can represent paragraphs of varying lengths.

Example:

`**BEFORE:**

```
   Dummy text. website.dk/info
   Dummy text (website.com) Dummy text.
   Dummy text. website.dk
   Dummy text. www.website.com
```

**AFTER:**

```
   Dummy text. <em><a href="http://website.dk/info" target="blank">website.dk/info</a></em>
   Dummy text (<em><a href="http://website.com" target="blank">website.com</a></em>) dummy text.
   Dummy text. <em><a href="http://website.dk" target="blank">website.dk</a></em>
   Dummy text. <em><a href="http://website.com" target="blank">www.website.com</a></em>`
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that "before" is only a list of URLs:

1. Find > Replace...
2. Click `.*` to enable regex
3. Enter `(.+)` into "Find What"
4. Enter `<em><a href="http://\1" target="blank">\1</a></em>` into "Replace With"
5. Click "Replace All"

If "before" is not all URLs the "Find What" will be trickier.

---

Per the comments, here's a (hacky) Python approach.

## file.html

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>
    Dummy text. website.dk/info
    Dummy text (website.com) Dummy text.
    Dummy text. website.dk
    Dummy text. www.website.com
  </p>
  <p>
    Dummy text. <em><a href="http://website.dk/info" target="blank">website.dk/info</a></em>
    Dummy text (<em><a href="http://website.com" target="blank">website.com</a></em>) dummy text.
    Dummy text. <em><a href="http://website.dk" target="blank">website.dk</a></em>
    Dummy text. <em><a href="http://website.com" target="blank">www.website.com</a></em>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

## link_links.py

```
import re;

def link_links(m):
  # Link all links.
  return re.sub(
    # Experiment with this pattern; e.g., search for "URL regex".
    r'(?<=\W)((?:www\.)?\w+\.\w+(?:\/\S+)*)',
    '<em><a href="http://\\1" target="blank">\1</a></em>',
    m.group(0)
  )

with open("file.html", "r") as html:
  match_non_html_re = re.compile(r'''
    (?<=>) # After a closing HTML tag
    [^<]+ # Match all non-HTML
    (?=<) # Ensure it is followed by an opening HTML tag (since we cannot use atomic grouping)
    (?!<\/a>) # Ensure we were not within a link tag already
  ''', re.VERBOSE)
  print re.sub(match_non_html_re, link_links, html.read())
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Sorry I was unclear. I revised the question. "Before" is not a list. The websites.com are in paragraphs of text.

Comment: This pattern works based on your example: `(?<=\W)((?:www\.)?\w+\.\w+(?:\/\S+)*)`. However, remember that the success of a regex is tied to the variability of what you're looking for and what it's contained within. Is the source file plain text or HTML?

Comment: It's HTML. I'm making WordPress posts from magazine articles. They have lots of email addresses in them.

Comment: Do you have to use Sublime? The better approach is to use a language (Perl, Ruby, Python, etc.) where you can execute code in the replacement. This will allow you to isolate all the non-HTML content. There may still be a Sublime approach. Can you link me to an example article?

Comment: I have no experience with those languages, but I have no objection to using one.

Comment: I've added a Python example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have more text that aren't links, then you can use a regex like this:

```
((?:www\.)?\w+\.?\w+\/?\w+)
```

With this replacement string

```
<em><a href="http://$1" target="blank">$1</a></em>
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qO6aL9/1)**

[image]